# PHP Multiline regexp

Tags: php, regex

Hello everyone I am trying to create a regexp for PHP that will allow me to get the quote and the author. I have made it work if everything is one line but the moment it is put in multiple lines it stops working. What am I doing wrong?

```
(\[quote\])(.*)(\|)(.*)(\[\/quote\])
```

> [quote]Silence in the boatyard,  Silence in the street,  The Locks and
>   Quays of Haganport  Will rob you while you sleep.|-popular children's
>   rhyme[/quote]
>
> [quote]Silence you sleep.|-popular children's rhyme[/quote]

Comment: Use the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (append if after the regex delimiter).

Comment: I am sorry @trincot is used (\[quote\])(.*)\S(\|)(.*)(\[\/quote\]) and still didn't work. It still find the online but not the multiline

Comment: @Martin I am quite new with regex - where should I put the delimeters? I have tried the ([quote])(.*)\S(\|)(.*)([\/quote])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/3l6bwi/1)

```
\[quote\](.*?)\|-(.*?)\[\/quote\]
```

**Note**: The regex above uses the `s` modifier. Alternatively, you can replace `.` with `[\s\S]` and disable the `s` modifier

#### Usage

```
$re = '/\[quote\](.*?)\|-(.*?)\[\/quote\]/s';
$str = '[quote]Silence in the boatyard, Silence in the street, The Locks and Quays of Haganport Will rob you while you sleep.|-popular children\'s rhyme[/quote]

[quote]Silence you sleep.|-popular children\'s rhyme[/quote]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

---

### Results

#### Input

> [quote]Silence in the boatyard, Silence in the street, The Locks and
>   Quays of Haganport Will rob you while you sleep.|-popular children's
>   rhyme[/quote]
>
> [quote]Silence you sleep.|-popular children's rhyme[/quote]

#### Output

The output below is organized by group (separated by newline)

```
Silence in the boatyard, Silence in the street, The Locks and Quays of Haganport Will rob you while you sleep.
popular children's rhyme

Silence you sleep.
popular children's rhyme
```

---

### Explanation

- `\[quote\]` Match this literally (backslashes escaping the following character)
- `(.*?)` Capture any character any number of times, but as few as possible into capture group 1
- `\|-` Match this literally (backslashes escaping the following character)
- `(.*?)` Capture any character any number of times, but as few as possible into capture group 2
- `\[\/quote\]` Match this literally (backslashes escaping the following character)

Comment: $parsed_string = "[quote]
Silence in the 
boatyard, |-popular children's rhyme[/quote]";
$pattern = '/\[quote\](.*?)\|-(.*?)\[\/quote\]/s';
$parsed_string =  preg_replace($pattern,'<blockquote>\2<div class="author">-- \4</div></blockquote>', $parsed_string);

I am trying to use this but I am only getting the second part "popular children's rhyme
"

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`s` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (append if after the regex delimiter). Also, make your `.*` non-greedy by adding a `?`:

```
preg_match_all("~\[quote\](.*?)\|(.*?)\[/quote\]~s", $s, $results,  PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Output is in `$results`:

```
[
    [
        "[quote]Silence in the boatyard, Silence in the street, The Locks and Quays of Haganport Will rob you while you sleep.|-popular children's rhyme[/quote]",
        "Silence in the boatyard, Silence in the street, The Locks and Quays of Haganport Will rob you while you sleep.",
        "-popular children's rhyme"
    ], [
        "[quote]Silence you sleep.|-popular children's rhyme[/quote]",
        "Silence you sleep.",
        "-popular children's rhyme"
    ]
]
```

Comment: 1. You don't need to escape `|` provided that it occurs outside of a group, nor the `/` if that's not also the delimiter. 2. You can make the attribution section optional with `~\[quote\](.*?)(?:\|(.*?))?\[/quote\]~s`

Comment: @Sammitch, I take your points, except the first. An unescaped pipe (`|`) functions as an OR-operator whether it is inside or outside of a group -- in the latter case the OR concerns the whole pattern.